# wget recursion problems

Tags: wget

Is there any way to get `wget` to recursively download from one starting URL (including every prerequisites) and include other paths for which the same will be done?

To make this clearer: The file `index.html` in `http://www.domain1.com/path1/index.html` links to several images, style sheets etc. This is what the `-p` option is for. But what if `index.html` links to `http://www.domain2.com/path2/site.html` which I also want to download (of course including its prerequisites, too)? If this second site `site.html` would link to other sites they should not be included.

I have already tried to add the second path via the `--accept-regex` option but this didn't result in the desired behaviour.

Comment: Have you tried adding the `-r -l 1` options? FWIW, the wget docs suggest a few extra options that are useful when using `-p`: `wget -E -H -k -K -p http://SITE/DOCUMENT`; please see the wget man page for details.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different restrictions you can place on wget to achieve what you're trying to accomplish, using your example.

Related options:

`-D` allows you to provide a comma-separated list of accepted domains - for example, `-D domain1.com,domain2.com` would ensure you only download files from those two domains.

`-l` allows you to specify the maximum recursion depth - using your own explanation, an example would be `-l 1`, which would mean if domain1's index.html lead to domain2's site.html, site.html would be downloaded, but nothing that site.html links to. Although `-l` is rather restrictive, you can run `wget` multiple times with different restrictions to obtain all of the files you require.